# Sorting ListView With Multiple Texts In Each

Tags: java, android

I have a Listview setup as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/topspacer"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="                              "/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/aisle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subaisle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/typee"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bottomspacer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="                              "/>
```

Each one of those is written by data received from a MySQL Database. I want to sort the entire list by the "Aisle" number, starting from 1 and progressing through 10.

what would be the best way to do this, I haven't found a solid answer, and everything I've tried doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide some examples of the things that you have tried (and how they didn't work, specifically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you query your database, you can specify a sort order for the results.
Use "aisle asc" or "aisle desc" to sort in ascending or descending order respectively. "aisle" is the name of the aisle column in your table.

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#query(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String)) for more details.

Comment: Scratch, worked perfectly. Aisle was Varchar and subaisle was tiny int. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post your table structure?